# Fix cleveref ?? prefix with floatrow

Tags: cleveref, floatrow, rmarkdown

I am following [the solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50717459/11021886) to add captions and cross-references to code chunks in an `.Rmd` file.

I would like to use `cleveref` to refer to these code chunks. However, currently my `\cref`'s are being prefixed by `??`. How can I fix my code to prevent this?

---

[image: Don't look at me. I'm hideous.]

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


% Extra bits for context
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}


% Make a new chunk float to attach label and caption to
\DeclareNewFloatType{chunk}{placement=H, fileext=chk, name=}
\captionsetup{options=chunk}
\renewcommand{\thechunk}{Chunk~\thesection.\arabic{chunk}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chunk}{chapter}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{## Assign the value 5 to x}
\NormalTok{x =}\StringTok{ }\DecValTok{5}
\NormalTok{x}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\captionof{chunk}{This is an example of a code caption.}\label{chk:example}

In \cref{chk:example} we do computering.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `\crefname` &  `\Crefname`. I took the opportunity to simplify a bit your code.

```
 \documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


% Extra bits for context
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}

% Make a new chunk float to attach label and caption to
\DeclareNewFloatType{chunk}{placement=H, fileext=chk, within=section, name=Chunk}
\crefname{chunk}{chunk}{chunks}
\Crefname{chunk}{Chunk}{Chunks}

\begin{document}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{## Assign the value 5 to x}
\NormalTok{x =}\StringTok{ }\DecValTok{5}
\NormalTok{x}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\captionof{chunk}{This is an example of a code caption.}\label{chk:example}

In \cref{chk:example} we do computering.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem.